# A server cannot receive TCP packet which size is bigger than 1500 byte

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, mtu

There is one server cannot receive TCP packet which size is larger than 1500 bytes,
but  this server CAN send out a TCP packet larger than 1500.

I also try to capture packet in this server for analyzing by WireShark.
However, WireShark cannot capture packets normally in this server.
(e.g.some received packets doesn't be captured by WireShark)

Anyone has idea? Thanks a lot.

Server info.
OS: Windows 2008;
MTU: 1500.

===================================================
Let me describe this question more clearly.
I have a client/server program which create a TCP connection between 2 server
and the situation is as below
Server_A ---- Server_B
         ---> pkt <1500 Byte     cannot receive
         ---> pkt >1500 Byte     can receive
         <--- pkt <1500 Byte     can receive
         <--- pkt >1500 Byte     can receive

This program works well in other server, only abnormal in server_B.
Any one has this experience?

Comment: If the mtu is 1500, then a server can send a TCP packet larger than 1500 bytes, but the IP layer will fragment the packet so that the resulting IP datagrams are not bigger than the mtu

Comment: yes, in normal case my program can send a packet bigger than 1500. But in this case, a specific server, I create a TCP connection between server_A and server_B. And I send a packet to server_B. When the packet size is smaller than 1500, my program in server_B can receive the packet. But if bigger than 1500, it cannot.

Comment: I think at this point if you posted a code snippet it would help.  When make code that writes to a TCP socket in Linux/Unix, I just do a write() system call, giving it a pointer to the buffer and its length.  The OS then tell me how much was written.  If the OS doesn't write the whole buffer I call write() again with a pointer to the bytes that were not sent.

Comment: This was probably cause by a pMTU black hole due to someone who thinks that ICMP is optional and thus it's perfectly fine to configure a firewall to block it. ICMP is an Internet endpoint *requirement* and blocking it breaks things like TCP.

Answer (score 1):

> When the packet size is smaller than 1500, my program in server_B can receive the packet. But if bigger than 1500, it cannot.

TCP isn't a messaging protocol. It's a byte-stream protocol. Keep reading.